# PySpark add multiple columns based on categories from the other column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
id | category | value
---+----------+------
1  | a        | 3
2  | a        | 3
3  | a        | 3
3  | b        | 1
4  | a        | 1
4  | b        | abc
```

The output I want is:

```
id | category_a | category_b
---+------------+--------
1  | 3          | null
2  | 3          | null
3  | 3          | 1
4  | 1          | abc
```

It means that it will `groupBy` `id, category` and creates dummy columns.

How can I transform the input to the expected output?

My approach is:

```py
pivoted_df = df.groupBy("id") \
        .pivot("category") \
        .agg(F.lit(F.col("value")))
```

But I got this error:

```sh
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Aggregate expression required for pivot, but '`value`' did not appear in any aggregate function.;
```

**Update:** The `value` column contains non-numeric value also.

For the `category` column, each `id` will have 2 rows only with respect to 2 categories `a, b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.groupBy('id').pivot('category').agg(F.first('value'))
```

Comment: Does it work with non-numeric values? Sorry, I forgot to add to the example, the `value` column contains text value also.

Comment: For string type data, consider using the ```first``` function.